# Pandas: filter dataframe with type of data

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe. It's a part

```
        member_id event_duration             domain           category
0          299819             17  element.yandex.ru               None
1          299819              0        mozilla.org          Программы
2          299819              4          vbmail.ru               None
3          299819              aaa          vbmail.ru               None
```

How filter df with type?
Usually I do it with `str.contains`, maybe it's normal to specify any like 
`df[df.event_duration.astype(int) == True]`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If all the other row values are valid as in they are not `NaN`, then you can convert the column to numeric using `to_numeric`, this will convert strings to `NaN`, you can then filter these out using `notnull`:

```
In [47]:
df[pd.to_numeric(df['event_duration'], errors='coerce').notnull()]

Out[47]:
   member_id event_duration             domain   category
0     299819             17  element.yandex.ru       None
1     299819              0        mozilla.org  Программы
2     299819              4          vbmail.ru       None
```

This:

```
df[df.event_duration.astype(int) == True]
```

won't work as the string will raise an `ValueError` exception as the string cannot be converted

Comment: Note you can & or | columns together. E.g: `df[(pd.to_numeric(df['event_duration'], errors='coerce').notnull() | pd.to_numeric(df['member_id'], errors='coerce').notnull())]` would return a dataframe with all rows where either `event_duration` OR `member_id` was not numeric.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [df.select_dtypes()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html).

```
df.select_dtypes("int")
```

Comment: This returns a subset of columns, not a subset of rows.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the above answers seem overly complex.  In most instances this should work where there are mixed datatypes in a column:

```
df[df['event_duration'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex as well.

```
df[df["event_duration"].str.contains(r"^\d+$")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Best_soultion:

```
df["event_duration"].transform(lambda x: x.fillna('') if x.dtype == 'float64' else x.float64(0))

df["event_duration"].transform(lambda x: x.replace('orange','5') if x.dtype == 'object' else x.fillna(0))
```

You can find all different str set in interger column.

```
s= set([x for x in df["event_duration"] if type(x).__name__ == "str"])
s
```

for ex. output:

```
apple
mango
```

Then you can filter it out like

```
df[df["event_duration"]!='apple'] 
#or 
df[df["event_duration"].isin(s)==False] #or True for reverse
```

or
coerce the error, you can do something like this

```
df["event_duration"] = pd.to_numeric(df["event_duration"], errors='coerce')
```